# JTable inside JScrollPane cell size and table size

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have this code for show some data inside a JTable:

```
public class ShowResults extends JFrame {

    public ShowResults(List<String> list) {

        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center
        setVisible(true);

        String[][] table_data = new String[pics.size()][table_header.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++) {   
            //Fill table with data
        }

        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(table_data, table_header)) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                //disable table editing
                return false;
            }
        };
        JScrollPane scroll_pane = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(scroll_pane);
    }
}
```

But table doesn't look as i expect. I would that scroll bar in only vertical (now is horizontal) and header of table show entire header names (now table is wrapped for some reason i don't know).
How can i do?

Comment: What is table_header? What is pics? Can you please provide a full running example. Also makes it easier to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would that scroll bar in only vertical (now is horizontal) and header of table show entire header names (now table is wrapped for some reason i don't know).*

The reason is you set a new [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) as the content pane's layout manager. This layout manager honors the components preferred size and therefore prevents the scroll pane resizes  as you wish. I'd leave the default layout manager, which is [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), and add the scroll pane to the `CENTER` location.

On the other hand, you should make your frame visible *after* adding all your components to its content pane.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a grid layout. Also try removing the    scroll_pane for now and see if that makes a difference. I ran into problems using JScrollPane myself.